# Attempted to load class "PHPExcel_Cell" from namespace in Symfony3

Tags: phpexcel, symfony

> Attempted to load class "PHPExcel_Cell" from namespace "ImportBundle\Traits".
>
> Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - ClassNotFoundException

I've tried to put `use PHPExcel\Cell;` but still can not work. I don't know how to load that class or holiuggiow to get column index as integer.

The reason I use the `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex` because I want use that method to get column index as integer.

Thank you in advance for helping.

```
private function test($objPHPExcel)
{
    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        $columnIndex = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
        
        // Get error when on this line
        echo PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($columnIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the namespcing problem that @Matteo has already answered:

> The reason I use the PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex because I want use that method to get column index as integer.

`stringFromColumnIndex()` takes a numeric column index (0, 1, 2, etc), and returns a string (A, B, C, etc), so the reverse of what you say you want to do;

And `getHighestColumn()` returns a string (A, B, C, etc) so you're trying to convert a string column address to a string column address by treating the string as an integer, which will treat any string address as a 0 according to PHP loose-typing rules.

You should be using `columnIndexFromString()` instead, which takes a string column address (A, B, C, etc) and returns a numeric (1, 2, 3, etc).

Comment: Working well with:

echo \PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($worksheet->getHighestDataColumn());

Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
    echo \PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($columnIndex)
```

instead of this:

```
    echo PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($columnIndex)
```

Comment: It has no error message any more but It's always return 'A'